# Rails - No route matches [POST] "/page/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create in rails portfolio. Displaying the list of all pages and single pages according to the given id works correctly. The problem appears when adding a new record to the database: No route matches [POST] "/ page / new" What is the cause of this? After going to page / new, the add form displays correctly.
The database is postgresql and I also use Active Storage.

migrate/

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up 
    create_table :pages do |t|

      t.string "name"
      t.string "description"
      t.string "github"
      t.string "website"
    end
    add_index("pages","id")
  end

  def down
    drop_table :pages
  end

end
```

page_controller.rb

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @page = Page.all
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

    if @page.save
    redirect_to @page
    else
      render 'new'
      end
    end


  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end

  private

  def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:name, :description, :github, :website)
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :page
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with scope: :pages, local: true do |form| %>

  <%= form.label "Name" %></br>
  <%= form.text_field :name %></br>

  <%= form.label "Description" %></br>
  <%= form.text_field :description %></br>

  <%= form.label "GitHub" %></br>
  <%= form.text_field :github %></br>

  <%= form.label "Website" %></br>
  <%= form.text_field :website %></br></br>

  <%= form.submit "Add" %></br>

<% end %>
```

model/page.rb

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
end
```

rails routes

```
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                           page_index GET    /page(.:format)                                                                          page#index
                                      POST   /page(.:format)                                                                          page#create
                             new_page GET    /page/new(.:format)                                                                      page#new
                            edit_page GET    /page/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                 page#edit
                                 page GET    /page/:id(.:format)                                                                      page#show
                                      PATCH  /page/:id(.:format)                                                                      page#update
                                      PUT    /page/:id(.:format)                                                                      page#update
                                      DELETE /page/:id(.:format)                                                                      page#destroy
        rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
           rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                     action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
        rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
  rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
        rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
         rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                              action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
       rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                      POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
    new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
   edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
        rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                      PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
            rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
                   rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
            update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
                 rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper pluralization is extremely important in Rails. `resources` are always plural:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
end
```

[Singular resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) do exist but its a less common scenario and I doubt its what you're trying to do here.

I don't really know where `scope: :users` in that form come from but its way off.

What you want is:

```
<%= form_with model: @page, local: true do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <div/>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_field :description %>
  <div/>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :github, "GitHub" %></br>
    <%= form.text_field :github %></br>
  <div/>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :website %></br>
    <%= form.text_field :website %></br></br>
  <div/>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Use `model: @page` to bind the form to a the model instance created in your controller.

The first argument to `label` should match the input you are labeling for accessability reasons as that creates the correct `for=` attribute. Rails will default to uppercasing the first letter anyways.

Dump the `<br>` tags. Its not 1999. Use a `<div>` or some other element to group inputs and labels and use CSS to style them.

Avoid adding text to the submit button like `<%= form.submit "Create" %>`. Use [the I18n system](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) instead as it lets you reuse the same form for creating and updating.